# How to use Google Login without plugin in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I have seen some websites who allows their users to register or log in with social networks. I want to do the same for my WordPress blog, I already started to learn about it, but the more I read, the more I am getting confused. That's why I am asking for the help here.

I want to allow my WordPress blog users to log in or register with Google. I Have already created Client ID, Email address, Client secret, Redirect URIs, JavaScript Origins. But I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Your question is broad enough that it is better answered by tutorials and introductory articles on google-login and oauth. The site is better suited for a Q/A style, with specific questions regarding specific problems. Without the irrelevant information, your question is reduced to: *"I want to allow my WordPress blog users to log in or register with Google. How do I do this without a WordPress plugin"*.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, but I haven't found any tutorial which can help me to do it with WordPress... I don't know where to go now... is there any coding tutorial about this on web?

Comment: I haven't used wordpress much, so I can't give you any authoritative answer. I doubt you will get one, but who knows.  As for where to go from here, you can figure out how oauth/google-login is done, without wordpress at all. I'm going to guess that this requires some kind of server-side language being executed, e.g. php, which then leads to you figuring out a way to execute php-code through wordpress. Maybe through this process you get a better understanding of what you actually need to know. Existing oauth plugins are written by someone with the similar need as you have. Check the source?

Comment: Why dont you want to use a plugin?

Comment: Thank You for the reply swalog... I will do the same as you say... Omer Farooq I don't want to be depend on any plugin and I want to learn it, thats why I don't want to use any plugin... :)

Answer (score -1):

Well using a plugin for this sort of functionality is absolutely recommended, because you dont have to care about the security and other issues. Even seasonal programmers get a bit confused using the OAuth library but to start with checkout this tutorial it is as simple as it can be.
http://www.w3resource.com/API/google-plus/tutorial.php

Either way you will have to still create your own plugin and once you get the data from the google api, you will have to use a function like wp_create_user or wp_insert_user to register those users. This is pretty much what a (free) out of box plugin can do for you.